# SpriteKit support multiple device orientations

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, device-orientation

I have a SpriteKit game which I want to support all orientations. Right now when I change the orientation, the node doesn't keep its position. I use the `SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill` for scaling, because it will keep the right sprite size.

When I start the game, the game player is positioned in the mid screen like this:

[image]

Then when I rotate the device, the position becomes like this:

[image]

**Here is my view controller code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {

        // Create and configure the scene.
        SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

        // Present the scene.
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

**And my scene code:**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

        //Add spaceship in the center of the view
        SKSpriteNode *spaceship = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship.png"];
        spaceship.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        [spaceship setScale:.3];
        [self addChild:spaceship];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sprite *does* keep its position after the scene resizes — you can see from your screenshots that it keeps the same horizontal and vertical distance from the lower left corner of the scene. The catch is that after the scene has resized, that *absolute* offset represents a different *relative* position in your scene.

Sprite Kit can resize a scene automatically, but the relative positioning of nodes after a scene resize isn't something it can do for you. There's no "right answer" to how a scene's content should be rearranged at a different size, because the arrangement of scene content is something your app defines.

Implement [`didChangeSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didChangeSize:) in your `SKScene` subclass, and put whatever logic you want there for moving your nodes.

For example, you could make it so nodes keep their positions as a relative proportion of the scene size using something like this:

```
- (void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize {
    for (SKNode *node in self.children) {
        CGPoint newPosition;
        newPosition.x = node.position.x / oldSize.width * self.frame.size.width;
        newPosition.y = node.position.y / oldSize.height * self.frame.size.height;
        node.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Depending on what's in your scene and you you've arranged it, you probably don't want that, though. For example, if you have HUD elements in each corner of your game scene, you might want them at a fixed offset from the corners, not a proportion of the scene size.

Comment: in my case, orientation change does not trigger didChangeSize:. Could it be OS update? doing this on iOS 8.1.

Comment: Whether your scene changes size when the view presenting it does is determined by the scene's [`scaleMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode).

Comment: I noticed that the SKScene maintained it scene's size irrespective to orientation change. I have to put a hook in GameViewController.m:viewWillTransitionToSize... to change scene.size explicitly. It triggers didChangeSize after that. Thanks to @rickster.

Comment: For reference: "As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method. When the interface orientation changes, UIKit calls this method on the window’s root view controller. That view controller then notifies its child view controllers, propagating the message throughout the view controller hierarchy."

Answer (score 1):

I add I similar issue and found this question. I solved differently, using the `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`, as stated by @GOR [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025967/spritekit-support-multiple-device-orientations#comment61211453_22026344).

I added the following code in my view controller (that manage the SKView and its SKScene)

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    //skView is my SKView object, with scaleMode SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill
    skView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    //currentScene is my SKScene object
    currentScene.size = skView.frame.size;

    //Then, as all the objects in my scene are children of a unique SKNode* background, I only relocate it 
    currentScene.background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentScene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(currentScene.frame));
}
```

and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3,

```
override func didChangeSize(_ oldSize: CGSize) {
    for node in self.children{
        let newPosition = CGPoint(x:node.position.x / oldSize.width * self.frame.size.width,y:node.position.y / oldSize.height * self.frame.size.height)
        node.position = newPosition
    }
}
```

Thus we are able to use a constant and initialise it in one line. Then in `node.position = newPosition` we can set the new position.
Also we are able to make use of the enhanced for loop leading to a much more elegant solution.